# Как начать отчет времени в расширении Google Chromе по открыванию браузера, а не по щелчку на определенной кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chrome-extension, расширения

**background.js:** start отвечает за начало отчета, как сделать чтоб отчет начинался не по кнопке , а просто по открытию браузера?

```
const commands = {
    start: newData => {
        data = newData;
        if (!interval) {
            interval = setInterval(() => {
                const time = data.time + common.getTimestamp() - data.start;
                sendTime(time);
                return;
            }, common.INTERVAL_TIME);
        }
        return {result: true, message: 'success', command: 'start'};
    },
    stop: newData => {
        if (interval) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
        }
        data = newData;
        const time = data.time;
        sendTime(time);
        return {result: true, message: 'success', command: 'stop'};
    },
    reset: newData => {
        if (newData === void 0) {
            data.time = 0;
            data.start = common.getTimestamp();
            data.laps = [];
            common.updateData(data);
        } else {
            data = newData;
        }
        sendTime(0);
        return {result: true, message: 'success', command: 'reset'};
    },
    show: newData => {
        data = newData;
        sendMessage({command: 'visible', data: true})
        return {result: true, message: 'success', command: 'show'};
    },
    hide: newData => {
        data = newData;
        sendMessage({command: 'visible', data: false})
        return {result: truj, message: 'success', command: 'hide'};
    },
    switch: () => {
        let command = '';
        if (data.running) {
            data.running = false;
            data.time += common.getTimestamp() - data.start;
            command = 'stop';
        } else {
            data.running = true;
            data.start = common.getTimestamp();
            command = 'start';
        }
        common.updateData(data);
        return commands[command](data);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос толком не понятен. Что мешает запустить команду? Все расширения запускаются при старте браузера отдельным процессом.
В манифесте

`"background": {
    "scripts": [
        "js/background.js"
    ]
}`

Ну и в конце `background.js`
`commands.start()`
Но по коду видно, что вы дали код только объекта `commands` и что вообще решает скрипт - не понятно. Поэтому я могу ошибаться.